# ESLint: How to find unnecessary "async" markers on functions?

Tags: typescript, promise, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'd like to remove any `async` modifiers from functions that do not need it.  Specifically, those that neither return a promise nor have any `await` calls should not be marked `async`.

I understand not everyone may want this, e.g. a legacy code base may have lots of these where the callers are not worth changing.  However for a new code base, I want to remove `async` wherever it's unnecessary, since that makes the function cleaner to use, and easier to test and reason about (it indicates the function does not rely on any asynchonous behavior - though it may still have async side effects).

It's easy for some of these to slip through, especially in cases where the only `await` call in an `async` function gets factored out, but the dev doesn't realize the function no longer needs to be async.

Is there some way to check this with ESLint or otherwise?  I came up short in a web search.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the TS rule: [@typescript-eslint/require-await](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/HEAD/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/require-await.md)

And the vanilla JS ESLint version: [require-await](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await)

That should prevent any useless `async` markings.

It properly flags a simple example:

```
export async function a() {
  return 1;
}
```